# How to find a specific row between two tables by a common column in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I'm using PostgreSQL and I have two tables like below:

```
table1:
id   title  content  mail_number

table2:
id   title   mail_date   mail_number
```

now in my codes, I have a special mail_number, and I want to find the row that has my mail_number! 
I want something like:

```
select * from table1 OR table2 where mail_number = (my_number)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can do something like this:

```
select id, title, content, NULL as mail_date, mail_number
from table1
where mail_number = <my_number>
union all
select id, title, NULL as content, mail_date, mail_number
from table1
where mail_number = <my_number>;
```

Comment: I would suggest to include `table_info` also to check from which tables `my_number` is available.

Comment: @YogeshSharma well I have a mail_number that can be in each of the tables but it can be only in one of them! there are no same mail_number in two tables